# PHP if greater than

Tags: php

I am trying to echo a specific message if the numerical value of `$mqmtxt` is greater than 20.

The value is in a txt file, the value is 7 so should be showing `NO WARN` but is showing `WARN`.  Not sure what I am missing here.

```
<?php
   $mqmtxt = file_get_contents("./MQM/mqmcount.txt");
   $mqmtxt = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $mqmtxt);
   if ($mqmtxt >= "20"){
      $mqmwarning = "WARN";
   }else{
      $mqmwarning = "NO WARN";
   }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="dispmqmcount"><?php echo $mqmtxt; ?></div>
        <div id="warning"><?php echo $mqmwarning; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `var_dump($mqmtxt);`?

Comment: change this line if ($mqmtxt >= "20"){   to if ($mqmtxt >= intval("20")){

Comment: You are making a string comparison, not a int comparison. Try [casting](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

Comment: Do the typecasting on $mqmtxt. The code would be like this  if ( (int)$mqmtxt >= 20) {....)

Comment: The answer below (and comment) both solved the issue, the dump was 7 as stated in the question.  Thank you all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing the string `"7"` with the string `"20"` and since `'7' > '2'` your if test passes and `WARN` is displayed. You need to convert both values to integer to correctly compare e.g.

```
if ((int)$mqmtxt >= 20) {
```

Comment: A variable is always implicitly converted to an integer during compare so your cast to `int` is unnecessary.

Comment: @emix *Always*?! Since you can use greater-than operators to compare strings too, that can't be true.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @deceze. You can compare strings, but before PHP does that, both sides are converted to `int`.

Comment: @emix You're saying both strings in `'foo' > 'bar'` are converted to ints before comparison?!

Comment: You took my words too literally ;) Of course there's this type juggling magic involved.